# How to write a makefile for programs that i want to run on windows

Tags: windows

How to write a makefile for programs that i want to run on windows. 
I want to use make files to compile the code instead of vc8 UI compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makefiles for Windows are just the same as those for other systems; no different at all.  Here's an example one from [Microsoft's own reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6bt6xe7.aspx):

```
# Sample makefile

!include <win32.mak>

all: simple.exe challeng.exe

.c.obj:
  $(cc) $(cdebug) $(cflags) $(cvars) $*.c

simple.exe: simple.obj
  $(link) $(ldebug) $(conflags) -out:simple.exe simple.obj $(conlibs) lsapi32.lib

challeng.exe: challeng.obj md4c.obj
  $(link) $(ldebug) $(conflags) -out:challeng.exe $** $(conlibs) lsapi32.lib
```

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Program Maintenance Utility (NMAKE.EXE) is a tool that builds projects based on commands contained in a description file.

[NMAKE Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha.aspx)